# android service not working fine in a few devices

Tags: android, service

Why is my Service working perfectly fine in `MOTOG second gen` and `lenovo a1000` but not getting restarted immediately in `motoG` and `LG L90`.Am I missing somthing?

```
public class CreatingServiceForL extends Service
{
Handler handler;
Hello helloObj;
ActivityManager manager;

public void checkActivity()
{
    handler = new Handler();
    ActivityRunnable  activityRunnable = new  ActivityRunnable();
    handler.postDelayed(activityRunnable, 1000);
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    checkActivity();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    manager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    helloObj=new Hello(this);

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service created",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}


private class ActivityRunnable implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
    //doing something
    }
}
}
```

In the phones it does not work ,in `Setting>apps>running>myapp` the Service is stuck at "Restarting" for long durations.
I am still a beginner in Android programming and do not quiet understand different behaviour of applications in different phones.Any help is appreciated..!

Comment: I have also faced the same problem in some of the devices that the service is not restarted after manually killing the application.

Comment: service will not be restarted after manually killing the service.I am talking about the situation when OS itself kills the service

Comment: You didn't get my point. Leave that manual killing. My point of telling is that I have also faced the same issue of restarting service in some of the devices.

Comment: I found this problem is because android does not necessarily restart a service returning START_STICKY after version 4.4.2.Have not found any suitable workaround though.Wonder how whatsapp's service always restart

Comment: did you get any solution for Lenovo a1000 ?

Comment: does anyone have solution?